# How to combine (files under) directories from two branches, while preserving files' histories?

Tags: git

I am trying to split `my_branch` into multiple branches since it is too big for a single PR into `other_branch`. But while splitting, I want to retain history from `my_branch` for files under a specified directory (and its subdirectories) while retaining history from `other_branch` for all other directories (and their subdirectories).

There have been far too many large commits from multiple team-members into `my_branch` that `cherry-pick`ing commits pertaining to files under the specified directory is impossible.

Comment: So you want to cherry pick without cherry-picking?

Comment: You have to use `git rebase -i` a lot.

Answer (score 2):

If I understood you right, your problem with `cherry-pick`ing is not the `cherry-pick` itself but all the trouble you would have if you tried to do it manually.

I suggest you use [git rev-list](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-list) with `reverse`  and `--` to get all your commits that modified a specific path in chronological order and to user [xargs](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/xargs.1.html) to apply the `cherry-pick`s for you. From your ancestor branch you can do:

```
$ git checkout -b <branch_feature_1>
$ git rev-list --reverse <ancestor of my_branch and other_branch>..<my_branch> -- <directory_feature1> | xargs -n 1 git cherry-pick
```

Comment: You might want to generate the revisions list first, then do the cherry-pick operation with one original commit, with `-n` to avoid having Git commit it. You can then `git reset` or `git checkout HEAD -- <file>` various files to undo the changes, and commit the picked-apart commit. Repeat as needed with one commit until it's broken into many sensible smaller ones.

Answer (score 1):

> ... while splitting, I want to retain history from `my_branch` for files under a specified directory (and its subdirectories) while retaining history from `other_branch` for all other directories (and their subdirectories).

Git doesn't have file history.  Git has commits, which (a) *contain* files, and (b) *are* history.  So this request makes no sense: you start at commit `c123...`, say, which is currently the tip of `my_branch`.  Commit `c123...` has one parent commit, e.g., `c122...`, or two parents, e.g., `c122...` and `d345...` if `c123` is a merge commit.

That's the history of commit `c123...`: its parent is `c122...`, or its two parents are `c122...` and `d345...`.  Meanwhile commit `c123...` contains (some particular version of) files `dir1/file_a`, `dir1/file_b`, `dir2/file_x`, etc.  Parent commit `c122...` contains similar files—perhaps some or most of them have the same content as `c123...` and perhaps not.

The *history* is the series of commits, following each commit to its parent or, for merges, to all of its parents simultaneously.  The *content* of any one commit is the set of files attached to that commit, plus the metadata (author, committer, time-stamps, log message, and parent commit hashes).  That's all there is: everything else Git can show you is produced by *comparing* the contents of two commits.<sup>1</sup>

In short, you can't get what you want: Git doesn't have that kind of attribution.  There is no notion that it should follow `dir1/file_a` back through parent #1 while following `dir2/file_x` back through parent #2.  (But note that if, say, parent #1 doesn't *have* a `dir2/file_x`, then any attempt to follow `dir2/file_x` back through each path in history will fail when going from child to parent #1, and succeed when going from child to parent #2.  Whether this helps any, and if so how much, depends on a lot of other things.)

> There have been far too many large commits from multiple team-members ...

That's more of a process problem that has to be solved outside Git itself.

The [other answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53714073/1256452) (which I'm upvoting) has a procedure you might want to use, to cherry-pick (sort of) one commit at a time, effectively splitting up a big commit into many smaller commits.  Whether those are on branches is not really relevant: each commit is a complete snapshot of all of its files, as usual.

---

<sup>1</sup>For merge commits, Git will, when asked, compare one commit—the child—to multiple earlier commits, those being all of its parents.  Git calls these *combined diffs*, and they're sort of reductionist.  Git starts by doing the same pairwise comparing as usual.  By this, I mean it compares child vs parent #1, then compares child vs parent #2, and so on for as many parents as this merge has.  (Most merges have only two parents anyway.)  Then, however, by default, Git *throws out*, from this difference-set, any file where the child's version of the file matches that of *any one* of its parents.  This reduces the file-set to those files where the merge commit's copy of, say, `dir1/file_a` and `dir2/file_c` are *different* from *every* parent's copy of those two files.  Git then, by default for a combined diff, takes the diffs from each parent to the (single) child, finds the places where there would be a merge conflict if you were merging, and shows you the (combined) differences there, so that you can figure out how someone did the merge.